# my template engine file not rendered in my router file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

hello every one in this code i have a template engine file but not rendered and i havent a error
and i cant see it
i need a help in /admin/article/new
this is my module code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const Article = require('../models/article')
const User = require('./../models/users');

router.post('/signup', async(req, res, next) => {
    req.user = new User()
    next()
}, saveing());

function saveing() {
    return async(req, res) => {
        let user = req.user
        user.username = req.body.username
        user.password = req.body.password
        try {
            user = await user.save()
            res.send("ok saves")

            // res.render('article/new')

        } catch (e) {
            res.send("40004")
            console.log(e)
            console.log("error==============")
        }
    }
}

router.post('/signin', async(req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    if (user) {
        res.render('/admin/article/new', { article: new Article() })
    } else {
        res.send("400404040")
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is `/admin/article/new` in the `views` directory? Have you set the view engine for express?

Comment: I would suggest to check your errors. As far as I can tell you are using a wrong path to specify your view. I think your path should not start with a `/`  - try using `'admin/article/new'` + as @NickParsons said, make sure that your view engine is setup correctly.